# Fedora 23 freezes after login

Tags: linux, fedora, freeze

Fedora is my first Linux-based OS I've ever installed and everything seemed to be going well until I tried to log in. I enter my credentials and the login disappears leaving only the background image and the cursor. I'm a complete noob at this and I have no clue what to do. I've reinstalled 3 times and still have the same problem. I'm able to login through terminal, but don't know where to go once I'm logged in Any suggestions?
Edit: When I right click after logging in the screen goes static and fuzzy [image: Pic]

Comment: What happens if you right-click on the background image? Also, how are you getting to a terminal?

Comment: What happens if you move the cursor to the top left corner?

Comment: So I guess it's not termin but another login place (ctrl + alt + f2). When I right click the background image it goes fuzy and static.

Comment: Woah — that is either a bug or a hardware problem. What type of system is it, and what video card?

Comment: @mattdm My Cpu- i7 4770k, Asus z77 Sabertooth, graphics cards 2 gtx780s, 16 gb ram. Tell me if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think *maybe* it's actually just working. There *should* be a welcome/initial setup window, and a quick help screen when you close that, but maybe that's not working for some reason. (It'll only show up the first time.)

Is there a bar along the top that says "Activities"? Something like this:

[image]

If tha is what you are seeing, move the mouse up to the top left corner. You should then see a screen like this:

[image]

You can then either:

1. Start typing anything (no need to click again) to search applications (hit enter when the top result is what you want), or
2. Use the dash on the left: click one of the icons to open that app, or click the dot-pattern icon on the bottom to get a list of all applications.

Tip: you can also bring up this screen by pressing the "super" key (usually the one with the Windows logo). Combined with type-to-search, this is a really fast way to get around and launch things.

Comment: Fedora 23, and sorry I can't post a pic, I'm currently at school, but it definitly does not look like your screenshot.

Comment: I've added a "before" screenshot. Does it look like _that_? What happens if you press the "Windows" key?

Comment: I can't actually check because im in school but it looked nothing like that.

Comment: So, another possibility, if it's not the above: there's some hardware/video bug. We just signed of on Fedora 24, and it's to be released on Tuesday. You could try that to see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: I'll wait and try Fedora 24 on Tuesday and I'll try to get that screenshot up once I get home. You're probably right about the video/graphical issue.

Comment: Added a picture for reference if you would like to see